# Spring Data Sorting Array or Set into Pageable

Tags: java, spring-data

I have a List (or Set) of AirworhinessDirective:

```
@Entity
public class AirworthinessDirective {

    @Id
    private String issueNumber;

    private String casaCode;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-d")
    private LocalDate issueDate;

    private String title;

    private boolean isCancelled;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-d")
    private LocalDate effective;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String applicability;

    private AdRecurrence period;

    private String file;

    public AirworthinessDirective() {
    }

    public static AirworthinessDirective of(String issueNumber, String casaCode, LocalDate issueDate, String title, boolean isCancelled, LocalDate effective, String applicability, AdRecurrence period, String file) {

        AirworthinessDirective ad = new AirworthinessDirective();
        ad.issueNumber = issueNumber;
        ad.casaCode = casaCode;
        ad.issueDate = issueDate;
        ad.title = title;
        ad.isCancelled = isCancelled;
        ad.effective = effective;
        ad.applicability = applicability;
        ad.period = period;
        ad.file = file;
        return ad;
    }

    // accessors, equals, hashcode and builder ommitted
}
```

The two fields I would like to sort on are issueNumber and isCancelled.

I have this service method:

```
public Page<AirworthinessDirective> formPagedAds(int pg, List<AirworthinessDirective> ads) {
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pg, 10, standardAdSorting());
    int start = Math.toIntExact(pageable.getOffset());
    int end = (start + pageable.getPageSize()) > ads.size() ? ads.size() : (start + pageable.getPageSize());
    return new PageImpl<>(ads.subList(start, end), pageable, ads.size());
}
```

The same thing could be set up using a HashSet of AirworthinessDirective instead. I tried both because I thought the set may not order correctly (but this was not the cause). The `standardADSorting()` method is as follows:

```
    private Sort standardAdSorting() {
        List<Sort.Order> sortOrders = new ArrayList<>();
        sortOrders.add(Sort.Order.asc("isCancelled"));
        sortOrders.add(Sort.Order.desc("issueNumber"));
        return Sort.by(sortOrders);
    }
```

As I hope you can see, its intended to sort first by the isCancelled field, then by the issueNumber field. In other words, I want all the cancelled ADs at the back, otherwise, order by issueNumber.

What I am finding is that while the Pageable is set up, none of the sorting actually happens when I run this test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("embedded")
public class MaintenanceContractServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MaintenanceContractService.Default service;

    @Test
    public void formPagedAds_withUnsortedADs() {

        List<AirworthinessDirective> ads = new ArrayList<>();

        ads.add(AirworthinessDirective.of("AD/PA-31/75", "PA-31", LocalDate.of(2006, 12, 31),
                "King KFC 300 Autopilot Yaw Bridle Cable Clamps - Replacement - CANCELLED", true, null,
                null, null, "http://services.casa..."));
        ads.add(AirworthinessDirective.of("AD/PA-31/2009-13-06R1", "PA-31", null,
                "Forward Baggage Door Locking Mechanism - Inspection / Modification", false, LocalDate.of(2011, 11, 2),
                null, null, "http://services.casa..."));
        ads.add(AirworthinessDirective.of("AD/PA-31/33", "PA-31", LocalDate.of(2006, 12, 31),
                "Exhaust System Couplings - Inspection - CANCELLED", true, null,
                null, null, "http://services.casa..."));
        ads.add(AirworthinessDirective.of("AD/PA-31/104", "PA-31", LocalDate.of(2006, 12, 31),
                "Elevator Outboard Hinge Installation - CANCELLED", true, null,
                null, null, "http://services.casa..."));
        ads.add(AirworthinessDirective.of("AD/PA-31/97 Amdt 2", "PA-31", LocalDate.of(2006, 12, 31),
                "Horizontal Stabiliser and Elevator Outboard Hinge", false, null,
                null, null, "http://services.casa..."));
        ads.add(AirworthinessDirective.of("AD/PA-31/99 Amdt 1", "PA-31", LocalDate.of(2006, 12, 31),
                "Elevator Control Tube - CANCELLED", true, null,
                null, null, "http://services.casa..."));
        ads.add(AirworthinessDirective.of("AD/PA-31/90", "PA-31", LocalDate.of(2006, 12, 31),
                "Rudder Trim Mechanism - CANCELLED", true, null,
                null, null, "http://services.casa..."));
        ads.add(AirworthinessDirective.of("AD/PA-31/131", "PA-31", LocalDate.of(2006, 12, 31),
                "Nose Baggage Door - CANCELLED", true, null,
                null, null, "http://services.casa..."));
        ads.add(AirworthinessDirective.of("AD/PA-31/2016-08-18 (Correction)", "PA-31", null,
                "Inspection of the Fuel Hose Assembly and Turbocharger Support Assembly Clearance", false, LocalDate.of(2016, 6, 5),
                null, null, "http://services.casa..."));

        Page<AirworthinessDirective> page = service.formPagedAds(0, ads);

        assertThat(page, is(notNullValue()));
        assertThat(page.getTotalPages(), is(1));
        assertThat(page.getTotalElements(), is(9L));
        assertThat(page.getContent(), is(notNullValue()));
        assertThat(page.getContent().size(), is(9));

        // all asserts relating to ordering fail, basically everything is
        // in input order.
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I have to do additionally to get the sorting that I want?

Comment: You're missing the point of a Pageable. The point is to pass it as argument to a query method of a repository, so that Spring data modifies the query and asks the database to do the sorting and the pagination. If you have all the unsorted list in memory and return a sublist, well, you return that sublist. You can of course sort by yourself, using a comparator. You don't need Spring data to do that. Just use a comparator.

Comment: Ah! the comparator is a good idea: thanks. I guess I should have explained further, yes I am using spring data in many other areas in the way that you are implying. Its just that in this case, I have the data anyway through other processes, I just wanted to perform the sorting and get everything into a Pageable without doing another hit to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of JB Nizet, I was able to solve the issue using a comparator rather than using Spring Data to do the sorting. It came down to changing the `formPagedAds()` method to:

```
    public Page<AirworthinessDirective> formPagedAds(int pg, List<AirworthinessDirective> ads) {
        ads.sort(
                Comparator
                .comparing(AirworthinessDirective::isCancelled)
                .thenComparing(AirworthinessDirective::getIssueNumber)
        );

        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pg, 10, Sort.unsorted());
        int start = Math.toIntExact(pageable.getOffset());
        int end = (start + pageable.getPageSize()) > ads.size() ? ads.size() : (start + pageable.getPageSize());
        return new PageImpl<>(ads.subList(start, end), pageable, ads.size());
    }
```